# SQL "Insert into" with Vtiger

Tags: php, sql, vtiger

Ok so I know how to use `$row = $adb->query_result_rowdata($result, 0);` to query data.  How about an insert statement.  How would I run it and insert into a vtiger table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example of an insert statement. It inserts a new notification:

```
$adb->query("INSERT INTO `vtiger_notificationscheduler`
  (`schedulednotificationid`, `schedulednotificationname`, `active`,
  `notificationsubject`, `notificationbody`, `label`)
  VALUES
  ($newnotifyid, 'LBL_NEWNOTIFICATION_TITLE', 1, 'Notification Subject',
  'This is a reminder notification for ...', 'LBL_NEWNOTIFICATION_DESC');");
```

I've taken it from here: https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Developers_How_To%27s#How_to_Create_A_New_Notification

It would seem that more information about the `adb` object may be found here: 
http://api.vtiger.com/

Comment: HAha I would of never looked in the new notification area.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Glad to help. Some docu for vtiger seems a bit hidden ;-)